# Iterate over sparse matrix and concatenate data and indicies for each row

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I have a scenario where I have a dataframe and vocabulary file which I am trying to fit to the dataframe string columns. I am using scikit learn countVectorizer which produces a sparse matrix. I need to take the output of the sparse matrix and merge it with the dataframe for corresponding row in dataframe.

code:-

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
docs = ["You can catch more flies with honey than you can with vinegar.",
         "You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink.",
        "search not cleaning up on hard delete",
        "updating firmware version failed",
        "increase not service topology s memory",
        "Nothing Matching Here"
       ]
vocabulary = ["catch more","lead a horse", "increase service", "updating" , "search", "vinegar", "drink", "failed", "not"]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', vocabulary=vocabulary,lowercase=True,ngram_range=(0,19))

SpraseMatrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)

Below is sparse matrix output - 
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 5)    1
  (1, 6)    1
  (2, 4)    1
  (2, 8)    1
  (3, 3)    1
  (3, 7)    1
  (4, 8)    1
```

Now, What I am looking to do is build  a string for each row from sparse matrix and add it to the corresponding document.

Ex:- for doc 3 ("Updating firmware version failed") , I am looking to get "3:1 7:1 " from sparse matrix (i.e updating & failed column index and their frequency) and add this to doc's data frame's row 3.

I tried below , and it produces flatten output where as I am looking to get the submatrix based on the row index, loop through it and build a concated string for each row such as "3:1 7:1" , and finally then add this string as a new column to data frame for each corresponding row.

```
cx = SpraseMatrix .tocoo()
for i,j,v in zip(cx.row, cx.col, cx.data):
        print((i,j,v))

(0, 0, 1)
(0, 5, 1)
(1, 6, 1)
(2, 4, 1)
(2, 8, 1)
(3, 3, 1)
(3, 7, 1)
(4, 8, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely following what you want, but maybe the `lil` format will be easier to work with:

```
In [1122]: M = sparse.coo_matrix(([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],([0,0,1,2,2,3,3,4],[0,5,6,4,
      ...: 8,3,7,8])))
In [1123]: M
Out[1123]: 
<5x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 8 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [1124]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 5)    1
  (1, 6)    1
  (2, 4)    1
  (2, 8)    1
  (3, 3)    1
  (3, 7)    1
  (4, 8)    1
In [1125]: Ml = M.tolil()
In [1126]: Ml.data
Out[1126]: array([list([1, 1]), list([1]), list([1, 1]), list([1, 1]), list([1])], dtype=object)
In [1127]: Ml.rows
Out[1127]: array([list([0, 5]), list([6]), list([4, 8]), list([3, 7]), list([8])], dtype=object)
```

It's attributes are organized by row, which appears to be how you want it.

```
In [1130]: Ml.rows[3]
Out[1130]: [3, 7]

In [1135]: for i,(rd) in enumerate(zip(Ml.rows, Ml.data)):
      ...:     print(' '.join(['%s:%s'%ij for ij in zip(*rd)]))
      ...:      
0:1 5:1
6:1
4:1 8:1
3:1 7:1
8:1
```

You can also iterate through the rows of the `csr` format, but that requires a bit more math with the `.indptr` attribute.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. If possible, would like to checkout the .indptr approach as well. Many thanks !